# What the difference between gl_FragCoord in OpenGL and The ComputeScreenPos in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, hlsl

In OpenGL could use gl_FragCoord/resolution to get the coordinate of screen position, and in unity it could be calculated by the function ComputeScreenPos/w, but what the differnt of them? I am not so familiar to HLSL, if there is a similar variable like gl_FragCoord in HLSL, why not just use this?

Comment: Because Unity supports OpenGL, Direct3D and Metal, I don't think you like to write shaders for each API.

Comment: So, it just for compatibility? thanks